# How to get the correct time

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
// this creates the structure  
struct time
{
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
};

//function that calculates the time

struct time timeUpdate(struct time now)
{

    now.second = now.second + 1;

    if (now.second == 60)
    {
        now.second = 0;
        now.minute = now.minute + 1;

        if (now.minute == 60)
        {
            now.minute = 0;
            now.hour = now.hour + 1;
        }
            if (now.hour = 60)
            {
                now.hour = 0;
            }
    }
    return now;
}

//user input and output   
int main(void)
{
    struct time currentTime, nextTime;

    printf("Please enter the current time: ");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i\n", &currentTime.hour, &currentTime.minute, &currentTime.second);

    nextTime = timeUpdate(currentTime);

    printf("%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n", nextTime.hour, nextTime.minute, nextTime.second);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Are there 60 hours in a day??? And you must write `==` instead of `=` to compare hours.

Comment: wow i just failed math. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that your input is valid (0 <= hour <= 23 && 0 <= minute <= 59 && 0 <= second <= 59) here are my observations:

- in timeUpdate you say that now.hour = 60. You must check if now.hour is equal to 24 
  (`if (now.hour == 24)`)
  This is how your function should be:

  ```
  now.second = now.second + 1;

  if (now.second == 60)
  {
      now.second = 0;
      now.minute = now.minute + 1;

      if (now.minute == 60)
      {
          now.minute = 0;
          now.hour = now.hour + 1;

          if (now.hour == 24)
          {
              now.hour = 0;
          }
      }
  }

  return now;
  ```
- I deleted '\n' from scanf because I was confuse why the program does not show the result (I had to write a character and press enter key to see the result). Now that line looks like this `scanf("%i:%i:%i", &currentTime.hour, &currentTime.minute, &currentTime.second);`

Comment: thanx, i woke up and realized my mistake. 1. even though i wouldn't have gotten the right answer because of now.hour = 60, i was entering in the time the wrong way ( i did 23 55 55 instead of 23:55:55). 2. i should go back to grade school.

Second is it possible to use if=statements instead of nested if?

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: i meant else-if statements.

Comment: Than no, because one statement will be evaluated and the result can be wrong